# How to read data at certain block number on EOS?

Tags: database, chainbase

How to read data at certain block number on EOS?

e.g.
How could I read the data of a contract's table at certain block number?

Answer (score 1):

Reading a table at a certain block number isn't so easy since a block only records change in state, not the full state.

I think your best way forward is learning to use dfuse: https://www.dfuse.io

Comment: thx, but dfuse cannot solve my problem.